# Google Tag Manager - Specific Pixels (Cookies)

Tags: cookies, analytics, google-tag-manager, cookie-policy

Since GDPR is released we have to be following some rules to setting Cookies in users browsers. The problem is that we are serving all our Pixel's via Google Tag Manager, and the only way to exclude adding Cookies are to exclude the whole Google Tag Manager to load before consent is given.

What if i would want to be able to give the user ability to exclude and include some of the pixel's in Google Tag Manager.

**Let's say i have these Pixel's in my GTM container:**

*- Hotjar 

- Google Analytics 

- AdForm

- Google Ads

- Etc....*

The user need to exclude or include all of these Pixel's if i exclude or include the whole GTM container in Cookie consent. How i can i give the user ability to exclude only FEW of those?

So a user can practically allow HotJar and Google Analytics but not the other Pixel's. How can i achive this? I tried to think about excluding the HIT(payload) to be sent but a Cookie will be set anyway. This is not GDPR complaient.

Answer (score 0):

The GDPR [allow for cookies](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm)

> strictly necessary in order for the provider of an information society
>   service explicitly required by the user to provide that service.

Insofar as an opt-out cookie allows you to do something specifically requested by a user (plus it does not contain user specific information) I am pretty sure it's allowed. Basically all opt-out solutions use a cookie, including the one published on the website of the European commission:

> Cookie consent kit
>
> This solution provides the following functionalities:
>
> JavaScript to automatically display the header banner in 24 languages
>   a wizard to declare your cookies and the link to your cookies notice
>   page a JavaScript API with methods and functions that help to prevent
>   prior storage of cookies a **corporate‑consent cookie** to remember
>   the choice of the user across websites a template for the cookie
>   notice page.

So, just set a cookie with the user preferences.

Comment: So i can sett all Cookies but not send request to server if not accepted in Cookie Consent @Eike ?